# How to stop unauthorized access to a video file in php

Tags: php, file, video

How do I make it so that unauthorized people cannot see a video file, even if they get the location of the video? Is it possible at all with php? Also, the file will be uploaded by an authorized user. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Create a simple login script with php that checks a `$_SESSION` to see if they are allowed to see the movie.  If they aren't redirect them somewhere else.  Either that or put a directive in your `.htaccess` that allows based on location, or use `.htpasswd`

Comment: @Zak I created the login, but the login can't stop someone from viewing the file if they know the filepath.

Comment: @Zak How do you check if the session is set on a direct link to the video?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're going to want to put the video file outside of the document root so that that the video is inaccessible without PHP.  Then you can decide what sort of authorized user should have access, using PHP.

This principle is true for any sort of protected resource.  If it's in the document root (e.g. /var/www/html) then it is available to the rest of the world.  There are ways to protect resources inside the document root, such as Apache authorization modules.  But normally I would use PHP and put the resource outside the direct reach of the web server.

Comment: Yup, we do this, works out good to control access much more fluidly.

Comment: I like to build whole websites outside of the web root.

Comment: So basically, I should just put the entire video file contents into a php file which checks if the user is authenticated? Thank you!

Comment: @KingCoder11 - you should move the file outside of the `www` or `public_html` folder on your server then serve it using php. That way you can control who can see it in the php file that serves it.

Comment: Ok, that makes even more sense, then people can not view it. Thanks, but would my code still be able to access it for authorized users?

Comment: @Randall Out of curiosity (and since it's kind of of topic), how are you managing to stream the video (or rather how to go forward and back in the video) if it's passed through a PHP-file? I'm asking because I have had that issue. Playing from start worked, but jumping back and forth didn't.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson Oh, oops, not for videos... I was responding more about the general sense of putting items outside the webroot and using php to manage access. We don't care about videos, we just post those as public domain ;) So, I guess I was a bit off on that comment.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to putting it outside the directory root .. You can prevent direct access to it simply by adding a few lines to your `htaccess`

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www\.)?yourwebsite.com[NC] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www\.)?yourwebsite.com.*$ [NC] 
RewriteRule \.(mp4)$ - [F]
```

This will allow files with the extension of MP4 to be seen and embedded by your pages .. But not viewed directly ..

**EDIT**
For multiple extensions .. Just sperate them like so:

```
RewriteRule \.(mp4|mov|mkv)$ - [F]
```

Comment: Can I use the same line for all other video extensions as well?

Comment: See my edited Anser ^^

Comment: NP :)  Just wanted you to know "there's more than one way to skin a cat"

Comment: Just a side note. There are routers that actually clears the `HTTP_REFERER`-header for privacy reasons. In those cases, they would never be able to see the video. That header can also easily be manipulated. In general, you should never trust it. In most cases, this will however work, as long as you're not protecting any sensitive data this way.

Comment: :D Thanks, this way also seems easier to implement, but I have one small question, is it possible to do this for all extensions other than .php, that way people can't access anything other than whats necessary?

Comment: You can do this with images etc etc etc .. But as @Magnus stated .. I would not trust this with sensitive material .. Just as a way to keep nosy people from poking around your site ...

Comment: working fine for me - just an additional question: when using this, why is it still neccessary to put the video outside of the document root? direct access should be prevented anyways with this solution, or am I wrong with that?